# Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: document, id, password, username, username_id

Tags: django

Something is wrong with my models,or in the way I am trying to implement my algorithm.
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=80,blank=True)


class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Upload function(views.py)

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
            newdoc.uploaded_by = profile.request.user
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,'upload.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

I got fielderror at upload

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: document, id, password, username, username_id
```

It points to line 57

profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)

If I change this line

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(username = request.user)
```

I have this error

```
Exception Value:    
Profile matching query does not exist.
```

Is it possible to get more information form shell?
This works so far

```
In [3]: user = User.objects.get(username='drazen75')
In [6]: user.last_login
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 24, 7, 1, 2, 196411, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

My db schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "malex_document" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "docfile" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "date_uploaded" datetime NOT NULL, "uploaded_by_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "malex_profile" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
```

EDIT
Daniel suggested that I change profile field

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=80,blank=True)
```

Done,also migrations.
Again same problem.

```
File "/home/milenko/nup/malex/views.py" in upload
  57.             profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  403.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /upload/
Exception Value: Profile matching query does not exist.
```

sqlite schema output
.schema malex_profile

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "malex_profile" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "password" text NOT NULL, "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You are using `User.objects` in the shell, but in your code you have `Profile.objects` - `Profile` has no `user` attribute, it does have a _`username`_ attribute. Perhaps this is just a typo in your view?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you've called the field that links Profile to User `username`. You could change your query to use `username` instead, but really you should fix the field; it refers to the User, so it should be called `user`.

Comment: Daniel,I have auth_user.Take a look at my edit,please!

Comment: Well, do you have a Profile for that user? Did you create one?